# How I can solve System.ArgumentException: 'The node to insert is from another document context.'

Tags: c#, .net

I need help please, I have this code

```
public static void Main()
{
    XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
    doc1.Load(XML1);

    XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
    doc2.Load(XML2);

    XmlElement root = doc2.DocumentElement;
    var children1 = doc1.SelectNodes("root/data");
    //var children2 = doc2.SelectNodes("root/data");

    XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
    result.Load(ResultFile);

    XmlNodeList Xlist = result.SelectNodes("/root/data");
    for (var d = 0; d < children1.Count; d++) //lista  doc 1
    {
        var child = children1[d];
        XmlNode nodeToFind = root.SelectSingleNode("/data[@name='" + child.Attributes["name"].Value + "']");
        if (nodeToFind == null)
        {
            result.AppendChild(child);
        }
    }
```

I get an exception at this line: `result.AppendChild(child);`

What does that exception mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Each XmlNode may only belong to one document, so before you can add it to a different document you must first clone the node by calling ImportNode from destination XmlDocument. You should be able to append the imported clone.

Comment: Can you write code here, please

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to -

```
public static void Main()
{
            XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.Load(XML1);

            XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
            doc2.Load(XML2);

            XmlElement root = doc2.DocumentElement;
            var children1 = doc1.SelectNodes("root/data");
            //var children2 = doc2.SelectNodes("root/data");

            XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
            result.Load(ResultFile);

            XmlNode XNode = result.SelectSingleNode("/root");
            for (var d = 0; d < children1.Count; d++) //lista  doc 1
            {
                var child = children1[d];
                XmlNode nodeToFind = root.SelectSingleNode("/data[@name='" + child.Attributes["name"].Value + "']");
                if (nodeToFind == null)
                {
                    XNode.AppendChild(result.ImportNode(child, true));

                }
            }

            result.Save(ResultFile);
}
```